# Erlang error in process with exit value undef

Tags: erlang

Ive been trying to write a simple concurrency exercise in Erlang that invlolves communicating across different terminals/shells.

However this error appears everytime I run init_chat() and entering my name.

> =ERROR REPORT==== 15-Nov-2021::08:13:11.849169 === Error in process <0.91.0> on node kei@osboxes with exit value:
> {undef,[{chat,chat_handle,"Jeano",[]}]}

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The whole program:

```
-module(chat).
-compile(export_all).

init_chat() ->
    In = io:get_line("Name please: "),
    Name = string:trim(In),
    register(chat_handle, spawn(chat, chat_handle, [Name])).

chat_handle(Name) ->
    spawn(chat, message_handle, [Name]),
    receive
        {message, Sender, Message} ->
            io:format("~p: ~p", [Sender, Message]),
            chat_handle(Name);
        {dc, Sender} ->
            io:format("~p Has disconnected. ~n", [Sender]),
            chat_handle(Name);
        quit ->
            io:format("Disconnecting... ~n"),
            erlang:halt()
    end.

message_handle(Name) ->
    Message = io:get_line("You: "),
    if
        Message == "bye/n" ->
            disconnect(nodes(), Name);
        true ->
            send_message(nodes(), Name, Message)
    end.

send_message([Head | Tail], Name, Message) ->
    {chat_handle, Head} ! {message, Name, Message},
    send_message(Tail, Name, Message);
send_message([], Name, Message) ->
    message_handle(Name).

disconnect([Head | Tail], Name) ->
    {chat_handle, Head} ! {dc, Name},
    disconnect(Tail, Name);
disconnect([], Name) ->
    {chat_handle, node()} ! quit.
```

Comment: I think Richard probably hit the exact problem you have in this case, but more generally introduction to chat systems in Erlang are *really* good to explore when you're new, and to that end you may find this series (and related repo) useful to explore: https://rumble.com/ve8h9r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says `{chat,chat_handle,"Jeano", ...` (which is missing list brackets around the string) but your code actually says `spawn(chat, chat_handle, [Name])`, which looks correct, so I think you just haven't reloaded the recompiled version of the module.